# Making cargo space even in Toyota Sienna?

Tags: toyota, interior, sienna

I recently bought a Toyota Sienna. I fold down the third row of seats in order to make space for my dog crates. Unfortunately, the space obtained by just folding down the seats is not flat and the crates tip over when I drive.

> Is there anything I can buy to make it even?

In the worst case I suppose I could use a piece of wood but I'd much rather have a piece of gear specifically designed for this purpose and this car model.

Comment: If you don't need the 3rd row seating, remove it, then put a piece of plywood in there to make it flat. To my knowledge there's nothing else you can really do which will make it flat.

Comment: You might have better luck asking this on pets.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I suppose this will depend in part on how else you plan to use the van and what year it is – IIRC I've seen Siennas where there was a way to fold the 3rd row down into the floor and get a very flat area. There are also companies that make custom dog crates that solve the problem (http://www.kustomkrates.com/sportdogs.html for example) but they are not inexpensive.

Comment: @dlu Thank you. These are indeed a little on the expensive side. Especially given that I already have a travel crate for each of my dogs for the car. I will go with a cargo liner and see if I can make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I found and ordered what is called a "cargo liner":

http://www.weathertech.com/toyota/2015/sienna/cargo-liner/

It looks like what I wanted. Kind of. It's made of rubber, I think, not hard plastic. But if it does turn out to be made of rubber I can always stick a wooden plank underneath it.

Either way, this should get the cargo space flat.